# Faster way of accessing elements than sets

Tags: python

I have a file called `classnames.txt` which is a pickled object, representing a python set.

Here's the initialization code:

```
import pickle

names = {"dummy value"}

with open("classnames.txt", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(names, f)
```

In another file, I write and read to `classnames.txt`, updating the pickled object as necessary. My main operations (in order of frequency, high to low) are finding elements in the set (`x not in s`), adding elements to set, and iterating over the set.

However, this whole process adds about 1-2 seconds of runtime, and the overall process seems inefficient to me. Is there a faster way to store and access this data?

Comment: Of course there is.  The concept you're looking for is a "database".  I would think that `sqlite`, which is built-in to Python, would be an ideal choice.

Comment: You probably should think about the "json" module

Comment: Off-topic: IMO putting binary data in a text file is kind of weird (and asking for trouble, too).

Comment: @Fredericka I did consider that, but I read in another SO post that sets are not serializable as json, and I wanted the O(1) lookup that sets provide

Comment: @martineau Hi, thank you for your comment, could you elaborate on why binary data in text file can cause trouble? I chose "rb" and "wb" because without it I was getting other errors

Comment: The trouble I was thinking of was the fact that `.txt` files are generally considered human-readable and clicking on one is likely to launch a text-editing application which would surely have trouble dealing with your file's contents. A file's extension is often used to indicate the type of data it contains and you're breaking the convention. Yes, you need to use binary files with `pickle` (with the possible exception of protocol version `0` which is "human-readable"), just don't give it *that* extension. I suggest using `.pkl` or maybe `.bin` (there's no standard for them AFAIK).

Comment: @TimRoberts Please don't post answers in the comments; post an answer instead please. Adding a link to [the `sqlite3` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) would help too. It'd also help to give examples of what OP wants to do, unless it's already covered in the docs.

Comment: Because (a) the line between what is an answer and what is a comment is extremely fuzzy, and (b) mine is not the One, True and Only possible path here.  It was a suggestion..

Comment: @Tim (a) I agree, but in this case, it's an answer. The question is "Is there a faster way ...?" and your answer is "Yes, use a database." (b) OP's not looking for the "One, True and Only possible path", just **a** faster way, and a database is one :)

Comment: @Tim For comparison, here's [an answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66728320/4518341) where OP was looking for a better way to handle 2D data, and the answer is also obvious (Pandas DataFrame).

Comment: Although I've accumulated rep points, I still have much to learn about the zeitgeist on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is. The concept you're looking for is a "database". I would think that sqlite, which is built-in to Python, would be an ideal choice.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html